# How do I remove an item from a listview using the button inside?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I looked at a lot of examples and managed to get this far, but i still can't get the button to delete the item from my array. How do i utilize remove(position) correctly?

public class adapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
public adapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {

    super(context, 0, users);
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    User user = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
    }

    TextView question = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question);
    TextView answer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answer);

    question.setText(user.name);
    answer.setText(user.hometown);

    ImageButton remove = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.removeButton);

    remove.setTag(position);

    remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            notifyDataSetChanged();}
        });

    return convertView;


    }
}
```

User List

```
public class User {
public String name;
public String hometown;

public User(String name, String hometown) {
    this.name = name;
    this.hometown = hometown;
}

public static ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add(new User("Hi", "hi"));
    users.add(new User("Marla", "San Francisco"));
    users.add(new User("Sarah", "San Marco"));
    return users;
}
```

}

Comment: where is your logcat???

Comment: I didn't keep the log, but after changing some stuff, I think it was due to using remove(position) incorrectly. How do i implement this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign position as a TAG to Button in GetView
2. OnClick of Button, remove that position item from ArrayList
3. To refresh ListView UI, call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method

This will help you,
[Delete a ListItem by clicking the ImageView within the ListItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030363/delete-a-listitem-by-clicking-the-imageview-within-the-listitem)

Answer (score 0):

You have
 ArrayList users

on the particular event remove the object for arrayList of users, and then call dapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method simply.

Comment: i tried users.remove(position) before but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this method in your adapter class.
   public void removeItem(int position){

   arrayList.remove(position);

   notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
2. Call above method from onClick of Button like.
   remove.setOnClickListener(new 
   View.OnClickListener(){

           @Override

           public void onClick(View view) {
          removeItem(position);}

           });
3. The reference link : [Listview delete item and Refresh - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663853/listview-delete-item-and-refresh-android)